# How to Convert date field in yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss” to Timestamp field(yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) in Hive)

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp

I have a date field in the format of yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss coming from a db2 source.I want to load into hive and convert to timestamp.

How do I achieve it ?

Comment: I tried using this concat(concat(substr(datefield,1,10),' '),substr(datefield,12,26)) it was working fine...but when I use

CAST(concat(concat(substr(datefield,1,10),' '),substr(datefield,12,26)) AS TIMESTAMP) gives me NULL...Any help appreciated.

Comment: edit your question and put your code there

Comment: It’s already in the time stamp format of hive, just keep the data type as time stamp, it should work. Refer the time stamp in this doc : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `unix_timestamp` and `from_unixtime` instead of the `substr` method that you are currently using.

```
select cast( 
           from_unixtime(
                unix_timestamp('2017-08-31-12:24:48' , 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss') 
           )
        as timestamp
);

+------------------------+--+
|          _c0           |
+------------------------+--+
| 2017-08-31 12:24:48.0  |
+------------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your source DB has `dot` in between the hours, minutes and seconds. Hive supports `:` in between them like: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Ref: [Hive Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

```
select
cast(
  concat(
    substr('2015-07-22-09.00.32',1,10), ' ', 
    substr('2015-07-22-09.00.32',12,2), ':', 
    substr('2015-07-22-09.00.32',15,2), ':', 
    substr('2015-07-22-09.00.32',18,2)
  ) AS TIMESTAMP
)
;
```

Comment: Yes...I tried it but CAST as TIMESTAMP is giving Null values.